# Rails: form_for in application wide footer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I started learning Rails for about a month now and I am working on a fairly simple project to improve my skills. It's a blog where editors can add articles and users can subscribe to a newsletter by adding their email. The homepage is an index view and their is a footer that shows up across all pages.

Here is my problem: I would like to include the form_for the newsletter on the footer that exists inside the application layout. That form has a specific model: Subscriber, which stores users emails.

What I've done so far is include the following on the Articles controller:

```
def index 
  @articles = Article.order(created_at: :desc).all  
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new 
end 

def create 
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
  if @subscriber.save 
    redirect_to '/home'
  else 
    render 'new'
  end 
end

def subscriber_params 
  params.require(:subscriber).permit(:email) 
end
```

In application.html.erb :

```
<%= form_for(@subscriber) do |f| %> 
  <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "email address" %> 
  <%= f.submit 'Sign up', :id => "signup" %> 
<% end %>
```

The form is displayed correctly on the index page only and it doesn't save to the database (without error).

I have tried using a before filter on the application controller as well as rendering a partial without any success.

Edit

Subscribers controller code:

```
def new 
@subscriber = Subscriber.new 
end 

def create 
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
  if @subscriber.save 
    redirect_to '/home'
  else 
    render 'new'
  end 
end

private 
def subscriber_params 
    params.require(:subscriber).permit(:email) 
end
```

Application controller:

```
before_action :create_new_subscriber 

def create_new_subscriber
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new 
end
```

Comment: Why is the subscriber create method within the Articles controller?  It should be within the Subscribers controller.  I can think of two ways to do this - one you can create a more generic form that calls the Subscrbier create on submission or you put @subscriber = Subscriber.new within the application controller and have a before action that creates the instance variable on every page.  I'd review the [form guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).  form_for is a nice short cut but you can write it manually to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @MageeWorld thank you for your answer. I created a Subscribers controller where I added a new and create action and put the "@subscriber = Subscriber.new" within the application controller and a before_action that should be inherited by all controllers. However the form is still not saving to the database for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: WHere is the subscribe controller code?